# The remote SSL client failed to provide a required certificate. reason: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: ssl, wcf, server, client, nettcpbinding

I have a WCF Client/Server Application with nettcp binding. Created self-signed cert a.cert and a.pfx

1. installed a.pfx on the server side through mmc snapin in the local computer ->personal folder
2. installed a.cert on the client in the local computer ->personal folder
   **Server code:**

````
`              host = new ServiceHost(typeof(implementclass));
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
                binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
                binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
                binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
                binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        
                host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
                    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
                    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "SingedByDevTestCA");

                host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =         System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myinterface), binding, new Uri("net.tcp://10.30.154.239:5000/implementclass"));                              
                host.Open();`
      ```

**Client code:**
````

`               NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();

```
            binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;

            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            binding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;             
            EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("SingedByDevTestCA");// dnsname
            //string uriStr = string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:5000/implementclass");
            string uriStr = string.Format("net.tcp://10.30.154.239:5000/implementclass");
            EndpointAddress addr = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(uriStr), identity);
            chn = new ChannelFactory<myinterface>(binding, addr);

            chn.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            StoreName.My,
            X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
            "02706242a08eb02b8f2a76896142b1222302012c");
            //This line is bc we are working with self signed certificate                
            chn.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;             
            idd = chn.CreateChannel();
```

```
Now calling the method from the client side 
 string y = idd.Upload(textBox1.Text);

causes an exception on the client side but more importantly is the error on the server side as indicated by the title. 



I read many articles about self signed certificated as not trusted certificates but I don't understand how to make this setup work? upload call works without transport = certificate.  
If I switch the certificates and install pfx ( cert+private key ) on the client side and only cert on the server side, upload call works.
Which way is it suppose to work. I read that private key has to be on the server side and only public key on the client side but it is not working this way.
```

Comment: I have some comments about what you said about the private key must be stored on the server side and the public key must be stored on the client side. Keeping private keys on the server side greatly increases the risk. The reason why the certificate is not trusted is either not added by the CA or is not in the correct format. You mentioned later that storing the PFX certificate on the client and the cer certificate on the server can be called normally, then I think the problem should be that the certificate format is incorrect.